# URI percent encoding: Postman vs Insomnia vs PHP http_build_query

Tags: php, http, uri, urlencode

I need to send a GET request with URI components including an e-mail address and a message string.

When I build this in [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest), I get something like the following URL:

```
https://www.server.com/path/page.html?email=test%40server.com&message=This%20is%20only%20a%20test
```

If I build the query parameters with [PHP's http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function, using the following code, the result is slightly different:

```php
$url = "https://www.server.com/path/page.html";
$parameters = [
    "email" => "test@server.com",
    "message" => "This is only a test",
];
echo $url . "?" . http_build_query($parameters);

// https://www.server.com/path/page.html?email=test%40server.com&message=This+is+only+a+test
```

However, if I do the same in [Postman](https://www.postman.com), I get the following:

```
https://www.server.com/path/page.html?email=test@server.com&message=This is only a test
```

So Insomnia encodes the `@` to `%40` and spaces to `%20`.

`http_build_query()` also encodes the `@` to `%40`, but uses `+` for spaces.

And Postman does not encode anything.

---

The problem is that the application receiving my request is having trouble with the encoded characters.

They insist I should **not** encode anything and use the URL such as the one Postman outputs.

I have learned I should always encode URI parameters.

Should I just follow the application's directions and send unencoded strings?

Comment: The application receiving your request does not get encoded characters. Their web server decodes things automatically. It is not possible to send a URL with spaces in it. You can change space encoding to `%20` by using `http_build_query($parameters, "", "&", \ PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);` Again, this is transparent to the server and should make no difference.

Comment: Thanks @miken32, but the `@` would still be a problem, not to mention other reserved characters.

Comment: ***this is transparent to the server and makes no difference***

Comment: **The problem is that the application receiving my request is having trouble with the encoded characters.**